Transformation between the canonical basis and the degraded Bell basis
I would like to know if the following results of mine made are correct.
My goal is to express the canonical basis $ \{ |00\rangle , |01\rangle , |10\rangle , |11\rangle  \} $ using a degraded Bell base by a factor of $c \in \mathbb{C}$. That means that the degraded Bell Base looks like this.
\begin{align*}
|\phi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|00\rangle +c|11\rangle )\\
|\phi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c^*|00\rangle -|11\rangle )\\
|\psi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|01\rangle +c|10\rangle )\\
|\psi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c^*|0​1\rangle -|10\rangle )
\end{align*}
In the following we denote $N := \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} $.
Let's find the passage matrix from Bell base to the canonical one.
$$  P_{Bell \to Canonical} = N \begin{bmatrix}
1 & c^* & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & c^* \\
0 & 0 & c & -1 \\
c & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
As $  P_{Canonical \to Bell} =P^{-1}_{Bell \to Canonical}$ we get
$$ P_{Canonical \to Bell} = N \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & c^* \\
c & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & c^* & 0 \\
0 & c & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Thus, moreover
\begin{align*}
|00\rangle  = N (|\phi^+_c\rangle  + c |\phi^-_c\rangle )\\
|01\rangle  = N (|\psi^+_c\rangle  + c |\psi^-_c\rangle )\\
|10\rangle  = N (c^* |\psi^+_c\rangle  - |\psi^-_c\rangle )\\
|11\rangle  = N (c^* |\phi^+_c\rangle  - |\phi^-_c\rangle )
\end{align*}
Is this correct? This is very important for me to know because I need it for numerics. Thank you in advance for your help.

seems to me that your first matrix sends canonical to your "Bell basis", not the other way around (eg if you multiply it by $(1,0,0,0)$ you get a "degraded Bell state")

@glS . Thk for your answer but I am not sure that you are correct. Indeed if I enter $(1;0;0;0)$ into my first matrix (that means the state $| \phi^+_c⟩$ I get the vector $(1,0,0,c)$ in the output which correspond exactly to $N(|00⟩+c|11⟩)$. As the first row of the vector (the nmbr $1$) correspond to the coordinate of $|00⟩$ the second one to $|01⟩$, the third one to $|10⟩$ and the last one with $c$ to $|11⟩$. So it  indeed give me the coordinate of $| \phi^+_c⟩$ in the canonical base.

@glS More precisally when you enter $(1;0;0;0)$ in the first matrix your are all ready working in the bell degraded base. That means that $(1;0;0;0) = 1 \cdot |ϕ^+_c⟩ +  0 \cdot |ϕ-_c⟩ + 0 \cdot | \psi^+_c⟩ + 0 \cdot | \psi^-_c⟩$. Or in words the first row (the one with $1$) correspond to the coordinate attributed to $ |ϕ^+_c⟩ $ the second row the coordinate attributed to $|ϕ^-_c⟩$  and so on. I hope I ve been clear enough. You can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

I understood why I did not get the correct result.
It's simply because in the book I am reading they just used, at the begining, a lightly different degraded Bell basis. More precisally this one:
\begin{align*}
|\phi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|00\rangle +c|11\rangle )\\
|\phi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c^*|00\rangle -|11\rangle )\\
|\psi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|01\rangle +c^*|10\rangle )\\
|\psi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c|0​1\rangle -|10\rangle )
\end{align*}
And following the same logic as in my question you obtain.
$  P_{Canonical \to Bell} =P^{-1}_{Bell \to Canonical}$ we get
$$ P_{Canonical \to Bell} = N \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & c^* \\
c & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & c & 0 \\
0 & c^* & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
